# Module to embed content in a iframe?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd like to add a button to every of my article pages, that would open a box containing an iframe code embedding for example the title, the content and the image of the article in another page.
Does it already exist a module doing this? I tried Iframe and Entity Iframe, couldn't get what I want though.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why would you insist it has to be iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your node--contenttype.tpl.php you can add a div (optionally with a textbox) which is hidden by default and fill it dynamically with the title and content of your node. Create a button that uses the colorbox module to show that div when pressed and your done.

```
<div>
  <textarea>
    <iframe>
      <h2><?php echo $node->title;?></h2>
      etc..
    </iframe>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Alternatively you could just use javascript to copy the content of your page to a div when the button is pressed.